# filter() from dplyr in R isn't working to create subsetted dataframe

Tags: r

so I am currently trying to susbet a dataframe of earthquake data in R using filter() to only get records from earthquakes in Montana and California but I am not having any luck, It mostly just tells me that such records do not exist and returns a 0.

Here is my code:

```
load(file = "Quake Data All Years.Rdata")
filter(allQuakeData, allQuakeData$place %in% c("CA","OK"))
```

Here is the output:

```
  [1] time            latitude        longitude       depth          
  [5] mag             magType         nst             gap            
  [9] dmin            rms             net             id             
 [13] updated         place           type            horizontalError
 [17] depthError      magError        magNst          status         
 [21] locationSource  magSource       year           
 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Here is the result of head(dput(df)) where df is the data frame (i used head because it is a very large df): [dput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOueU.png)

Here's an example with diamonds dataset from ggplot2:

```
filter(diamonds, (cut == "Ideal" | cut == "Premium"))
```

produces the following:

```
# A tibble: 35,342 x 10
carat     cut color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
<dbl>   <ord> <ord>   <ord> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23   Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21 Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  0.29 Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
4  0.23   Ideal     J     VS1  62.8    56   340  3.93  3.90  2.46
5  0.22 Premium     F     SI1  60.4    61   342  3.88  3.84  2.33
6  0.31   Ideal     J     SI2  62.2    54   344  4.35  4.37  2.71
7  0.20 Premium     E     SI2  60.2    62   345  3.79  3.75  2.27
8  0.32 Premium     E      I1  60.9    58   345  4.38  4.42  2.68
9  0.30   Ideal     I     SI2  62.0    54   348  4.31  4.34  2.68
10  0.24 Premium     I     VS1  62.5    57   355  3.97  3.94  2.47 
# ... with 35,332 more rows
```

Comment: Example data please :D

Comment: Perhaps there are no `CA` and `OK` in `place`. Can you paste the output of `dput(df)`, where `df` is your data frame, into your question?

Comment: I don't understand the upvote. No [MCVE] and even a guesswork answer has been met with a notice that modifications to the code were ineffective. How can this be a useful question if it is misleading @akrun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need the `$`

```
filter(allQuakeData, grepl("\\b(CA|OK)\\b", place))
```

Or with `str_detect`

```
allQuakeData %>%
    filter(str_detect(place, "\\b(CA|OK)\\b"))
```

Comment: It gives the same answer :(

Comment: There could be leading/lagging spaces in the `place` column.  Try the updated code

Comment: That produced the same result too :(

Comment: From the image showed, it seems like you have a substring "CA" instead of complete string.  Try with `grepl`

Comment: I'm unfortunately supposed to use only dplyr functions, but I did post a reproducible example

Comment: @MaggieGreco  You posted the `diamonds` dataset, which have an exact match,here it doesn't have.  `grepl` is a `base R` option

Comment: oh i see now what you did let me try

Comment: If you need `tidyverse` function for that, try with `str_detect` instead of `grepl`

Comment: Okay so your code snippet worked but only produces records from CA, not OK

Comment: May be because OK pattern is different

Comment: filter(allQuakeData, grepl("\\b(CA|Oklahoma|California|OK)\\b", place))     This worked! Thank you so much!